# Jenkins compile error with XCode cocoapod

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods, hockeyapp

I'm trying to get Jenkins working with my ios project which uses Cocoapods. I'm getting an error

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-HockeySDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

which I don't understand since if I go to my workspace in

```
/Users/matthewchung/.jenkins/jobs/myproject-ios/workspace
```

and open the workspace, I can build and compile without any errors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this issue. I was struggling with it for a while.  Jenkins wasn't finding any of the libs specified by CocoaPods.

The issue for us was that I wasn't telling Jenkins to compile the **workspace**.  Specifying a workspace, and scheme (instead of project/target) fixed the issue for us.